# Is there a word meaning "of or like the squid"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I would like to know if there is a word for being of or related to a squid like there are words for humans, eagles, and lions, i.e. hominine, aquiline, and leonine. I don't expect the word (if there is one) to end in "-ine"; I'm just trying to avoid using "squid-like."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you want is a rare one, and you can probably only get away with using it in specialized circles (biologists, zoologists) and that word is [cephalopodan](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cephalopodan):

> Adj. 1.  cephalopodan - relating or belonging to the class Cephalopoda

The class Cephalopoda, or the [cephalopods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod), is the class of mollusk to which squids, octopuses, cuttlefish, and nautiluses are members.

Comment: Since squids belong to the order Teuthoidea, you might refer to them more narrowly as _teuthoideal_. Regrettably, the OED doesn't list this word, though it does have an entry for _teuthology_ ("That branch of zoology which deals with cephalopods").

Comment: @SvenYargs Why *teuthoideal* rather than *teuthoidean* or another suffix? Is there a rule governing that formation?

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13: The word is unclaimed, so you get to choose the form that you like the look and sound of best. Rules governing the available choices are obscure, but I believe the most suitable options here would be -eal and -ean. One useful rule of thumb is to attach the least Baroque ending available to the root word; in this case, that disqualifies, for example, _teuthoideamic_, though you could make a case for _teuthoidal_ without the punultimate _e_, or even _teuthoidic_. But no one should use _teuthoidoid_ (except Richard Hell, if he decides to launch a new band).

Comment: @SvenYargs-  It seems there exists a (at least one) source using just plain [teuthoid](https://books.google.com/books?id=i1b0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=teuthoid&source=bl&ots=-WAlEgJm4r&sig=EULd3MuLlXvr6qPnpp2lUZn4LHE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvsq6iypvMAhXI4SYKHRIXDiMQ6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q=teuthoid&f=false)

Comment: @cobaltduck: Good point. That source is especially interesting because it distinguishes between "teuthoid squids" and "sepioid squids," which I would interpret as distinguishing between "squid squids" and "ink-emitting squids"; the former is a rather puzzling category.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider, [***nautiloid***](http://www.krissydowning.com/Squid.html)

> A [mollusk](http://bio.sunyorange.edu/updated2/pl%20new/11%20MOLLUSKS.htm) of the subclass Nautiloidea, including nautiluses and many fossil species that were abundant in the Ordovician and Silurian periods.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nautiloid)